# Is clob type using bad practice in PL/SQL code when you try to avoid to use magic numbers for string length?

Tags: oracle, types, plsql

Declaration of PL/SQL variable require setting length for **varchar2** like types:

```
declare
  query varchar2(2000);
begin
  for i in 1..100 loop
    query := query || to_char(i);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(query);
end;
/
```

I run in trap when product requirements changes so loop range become larger (set range to *1..1000* in my example) and I got error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : буфер символьных строк слишком маленький ошибка числа или значения ORA-06512: на  line 5
```

So I need to increase *query* length everywhere and even with some larger number to predicate future.

This is ugly. I am not expert of PL/SQL but by reading official docs I found **clob** type which doesn't require length and quick checks show me that code works!

PL/SQL code become less Pascal like and more Python/Ruby/Perl like. I really like it.

I apply type conversion only for dynamically built strings which are out of intensive loop usages.

Is such technique correct or I am wrong?

**PS** I am freshman to PL/SQL programming so ask such dumb question...

**PPS** One of working code (simplified):

```
queryStr := 'create or replace view "DATA_VIEW" ("DT", "MONEY", "EVENT") as ( ';
for eventRec in eventCur
loop
  queryStr := queryStr || 'select DT, MONEY, ' || eventRec.ID
    || ' EVENT from ' || eventRec.tbl || ' union ';
end loop;
queryStr := rtrim(queryStr, ' union ') || ')';
execute immediate queryStr;
commit;
```

Comment: the max in pl/sql would be varchar2(32767).  If you're generating dynamic queries larger than this, I'd probably question your approach altogether.  Clobs can technically save you, but I'd like to see what that query looks like!

Comment: @tbone So to be in defencive way I just need to declare each unpredicable length **VARCHAR2** as 32767 byte long?

Comment: @tbone I use such variable length strings for creating dynamic queries so they are out of any loops and have no performance issue (if you compare with looping on table rows)...

Comment: yes, if you think it will be a large string, go with varchar2(32767).  I'm not sure what you mean about creating the query.  Are you building a huge IN list? (where somecol IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3',...'val1000'...))

Comment: oh, no! there are no any large 'in'... One example it to create view on several tables dynamically (as table counts changes over the time).

Comment: can you give an actual working example? (your post isn't a query).

Comment: I don't put as it unrelated for a question. But look now.

Comment: I see, you're doing dynamic ddl, still surprised to see it get larger than 32k bytes (how many tables in that cursor???), but if you're worried go with a clob then.

Comment: It never exceed 32k but previous employer set length to 2000 and now it must be 5x times larger.... And this is not only one place of such code...

Comment: If I recall correctly, the max length of a VARCHAR2 variable in PL/SQL is 32K **bytes** - but in a table the max length of a VARCHAR2 column is 4000 **bytes**.  If your database uses a code page where 1 character = 1 byte, the max length of a column is 4000 characters.  If your database uses a code page where the size of a character is 2  bytes, the max length of a VARCHAR2 column is 2000 characters.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The [`CLOB`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref202) datatype is your only real option if you want to manipulate strings larger than 4000 bytes in SQL or 32 kB in PL/SQL.

The operations on `CLOB` are a bit more expensive than on `VARCHAR2` for small strings though, so you should only use the `CLOB` datatype when dealing with **large strings**. Thus the `VARCHAR2` datatype still has its uses, don't go overboard and replace all your strings with CLOBs.

Comment: Note, I don't replace every VARCHAR2 with CLOB. My main point that setting fixed length for dynamically build strings (which length depend on data content, not DDL) is ugly... Anyway thanks for interest +1

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example working code, what I understand is you want to dynamically generate a view definition which is made up of probably hundreds of union statements, each querying a different table.

Similar data stored in hundreds of different tables! Now thats a strange database architecture!!

anyways, just blindly replacing varcar2 with clob is not recommeneded from performance point of view.

Why dont you keep a counter/check for the number of records in your 'eventCur'(eventRec)?

Then you can optimally choose a value for that counter above which you could use clob datatype and below which a varchar2 datatype..

Comment: Thanks for interest to question. +1. I definitely must highlight that **clob** strings out of any expansive loop ))